# TypeScript does not recognize a union of type unknown and type Promise<unknown>

Tags: typescript, union-types

Consider the following example:

```
type ExampleOne = Promise<string> | string;
// Inferred type: `string | Promise<string>`.
```

TypeScript would infer the `ExampleOne` type as `string | Promise<string>`, which is correct.

But when I change `string` to `unknown`...:

```
type ExampleTwo = Promise<unknown> | unknown;
// Inferred type: `unknown`.
// Shouldn't be `unknown | Promise<unknown>`?
```

TypeScript now only infer `Example Two` as of `unknown`, which I think is incorrect. Shouldn't be `unknown | Promise<unknown>` as in the first example?

I've created a [sample in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=46#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQPIDtoF4oAKATgPZICWAzhADyXBHlYDmAfFAD5T2MsDcAKAD0QqAEksAMwhEiEACZRQkAFxQABjybNOhUhWp0G21uoB0AgcujxkaCABUA7iSj5iZKrQCuWANZYJE5Y7Fy+AUFYgiLiUjJyitZq6uGBwebCogDKABYk3qjyWADkwFAARtAp-mlYuh4GPjWRpgD8QA) to demonstrate that behavior.

**The question is:** How can I make TypeScript infer `ExampleTwo` as `unknown | Promise<unknown>`, which is the type I need? I prefer not to use any kind of type assertions, which I think would make this code error prone.

Comment: `unknown` is like `any` except only in input positions. A union type including `any` always collapses to `any` and `unknown` behaves the same way.

Comment: Oh – so there is no way to solve that?

Comment: Correct. If we think about `any` as a reference point, the reason a union including `any` collapses to just `any` is that `any` is broad enough to represent all types making the other cases irrelevant. `unknown` is designed the same way but it is like a sink.

Comment: Now I see that, thanks. If you want to make a proper answer, I would accept it. :)